# PUT vs POST for initiating synch up

Tags: rest, post, put, data-synchronization

If resource A needs to synch up with resource B, what kind of REST method will you choose to do that, POST/PUT and why?

Note that the request is only going to initiate the synch operation.

Answer (score 1):

PUT likely to create a new object. The POST operation is very generic and no specific meaning can be attached to it, so it can be. But i think you must use PATCH. http://restcookbook.com/HTTP%20Methods/patch/

Comment: I don't think PUT creates a new object.